# monkey-patching requests in django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, gevent

I am trying to make a django view make several asynchronous http requests and return combined data.

Here's an example that works in a separate file:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import requests


results = {}
processes = []
def fill_results(url, position):
    print(url, position, 'starting')
    results[position] = {'url': url, 'response': requests.get(url)}
    print(url, position, 'ready')


urls = ['http://www.accessgenealogy.com'] * 5


for position, url in enumerate(urls):
    processes.append(gevent.spawn(fill_results, url, position))

gevent.joinall(processes)
print(results)
```

the output I get is this:

```
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 0, 'starting')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 1, 'starting')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 2, 'starting')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 3, 'starting')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 4, 'starting')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 3, 'ready')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 0, 'ready')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 4, 'ready')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 2, 'ready')
('http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 1, 'ready')
{0: {'url': 'http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 'response': <Response [200]>}, 1: {'url': 'http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 'response': <Response [200]>}, 2: {'url': 'http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 'response': <Response [200]>}, 3: {'url': 'http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 'response': <Response [200]>}, 4: {'url': 'http://www.accessgenealogy.com', 'response': <Response [200]>}}
```

so the requests are indeed asychronous.

When I paste the same code into a django 1.9 view, the `monkey.patch_all()` breaks django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in cursor
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 523, in validate_thread_sharing
    % (self.alias, self._thread_ident, thread.get_ident()))
DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 140735166436112 and this is thread id 4488713392.
<Greenlet at 0x10b8c54b0: wrapper(use_static_handler=True, settings=None, pythonpath=None, verbosity=1, traceback=False, addrport='8000', no_color=False, use_ipv6=False, use_threading=True, use_reloader=True, insecure_serving=False)> failed with DatabaseError
```

what specifically should I patch to make this work without breaking django?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things:

1. Make sure you do not perform any database operations in greenlets
2. Import gevent and patch within your view, and then unpatch when you're done.

Here's an example:

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def fill_results(url, position):
            # Point 1: no DB operations inside here!
            results[position] = {'url': url, 'response': request.get(url)}

        urls = ['http://www.accessgenealogy.com'] * 5

        # import gevent and patch
        import gevent
        from gevent import monkey
        monkey.patch_all()

        processes = []
        for position, url in enumerate(urls):
            processes.append(gevent.spawn(fill_results, url, position))

        gevent.joinall(processes)

        # Point 2: unpatch after use
        reload(socket)

        return HttpResponse()
```